# how to change the bootstrap carousel direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following js code to change the direction of bootstrap carousel to 'ltr' in Arabic language. I need to change the direction of carousel to 'ltr' but the following js code is not working properly.

Is there anyone who will debug this problem.

JQuery

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
if(theLanguage == 'en') {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        direction:'left',
    });
}

else{

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        direction:'right',
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there anybody who have skill to change the direction of bootstrap carousel 'ltr' in arabic language and 'rtl' in English language

Comment: hope this will help,
[Twitter Bootstrap Carousel cycle items right to left ( RTL ) reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877562/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-cycle-items-right-to-left-rtl-reversed)

Comment: for browser language detection: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317523/5393271)

Comment: Thanks for your support its really gona work on my jquery file thank you

Comment: If the answer solved you issue, please accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

By overriding the cycle function you can make it call prev instead of next on each cycle.

[Take a look at my working example here](http://codepen.io/LukeXF/pen/yewQpe).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').each(function(){

        // find carousel
        $(this).carousel();

        var carousel = $(this).data('bs.carousel');

        // pause the cycle
        carousel.pause();

        // At first, reverse the order of the items in the carousel because we're moving backwards
        $(this).find('> .carousel-inner > .item:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
            $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
        });

        // Override the bootstrap carousel prototype function, adding a different one won't work
        carousel.cycle = function (e) {
            if (!e) this.paused = false
            if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.options.interval
            && !this.paused
            && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.prev, this), this.options.interval))
            return this;
        };

        // begin the cycle again
        carousel.cycle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest an extension of the carousel rather than just overriding its cycle method. You could just create a `ReversibleCarousel` for example and provide an additional method that did the same thing as your override does, but leaves the normal `cycle` method in place for later calls.