# How to Change Browser Language Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have detected my browser default language like this:

```
 <script defer type="text/javascript">
   (function(window, $) {
       var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
       alert(lang); // en_US
   })(window, jQuery);
 </script>
```

But I want to set my specific language(de_DE) on browser Chrome, Mozilla etc...

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You cannot change the user preferred language. It's a *user preferred* language, not "developer preferred language". For this reason, the `language` property is read-only. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317335/jquery-browser-language-detection

Comment: @IbrohimAlimuhammedov — Determining what the user's preference is is a very different problem to changing it.

Comment: When I open my site we got language german(de) properly, but when I open my site on mobile browse it is showing in English. I want german on my mobile also same as desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The browser language is the user's preference. Websites can't change it.

If you want to change the content of your website, then change the content (don't forget to update your `lang` attributes). This, obviously, won't affect the browser chrome.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have 1 issue when I open my site we got language german(de) properly, but when I open my site on mobile browse it is showing in English. I want german on my mobile also same as desktop

Comment: @RajeevSingh — Then change your mobile's language settings. If you don't know how then that's probably a question for https://android.stackexchange.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have no issue with change my phone browser language but my other customer also complain about the same issue, so it's not possible to change every customer mobile language setting. So I want to be set the default language and the browser don't affect my website default language.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time I will try something different about this happens.

Comment: I refer you back to the first two words of my answer.